# failed to create bus connection: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, docker, systemctl, dbus

1. Virtualbox with ubuntu 22.04

```
[root@container www]# systemctl start NetworkManager
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

2. Virtualbox with ubuntu 20.04

```
docker run --privileged -d -ti dev:centos7
drsr@ubuntu2004:~$ docker exec -it container bash
[root@container www]# systemctl status NetworkManager
    ● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: inactive (dead)
         Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
```

**What i tried:**

1. I tried to create /etc/docker/daemon.json with

```
{
"deprecatedCgroupv1": true
}
```

and restarted
systemctl restart docker.service

but unable to restart the service

2. ran with --privileged flag added

```
mkdir -p /run/dbus/system_bus_socket, 
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/1000'
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
```

but nothing works, the same image works with Ubuntu 20.04 but not with 22.04 strange.